# How do I determine each transaction fee on the blockchain?

Tags: transaction-fees

I would like to be able to see each transaction fee charged when I look at the transactions in a block.  How do I do this?

Comment: Please specify the client or platform you're using to view transactions. Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction fee is the difference between the value of the inputs being spent and the value of the outputs being created. Most block explorers will tell you the transaction fee for a transaction though, so you don't need to calculate it manually.

Comment: But if we want to check the fee before the transaction happen